# Mapped drives aren't syncing on workstations

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, mappeddrive

It seems like a few workstations on our network aren't syncing with the mapped drives, pretty randomly, so for example, different users on the same computer would see different files on the mapped drive, causing confusing and files to go missing once mapped drive are synced.

The mapped drives are configured via GPO and Home Folder. Workstations are all Windows 7 Professional

What is the best way to tackle this issue via GPO considering the following:

- Users don't have the "sync folder" button (I am not sure why)
- There is no need for a local "offline cache", so it would be best to just to maybe cancel it
- If anything is going to be synced before cancelling the offline cache, files should be uploaded if missing on the actual network drive, but not deleted

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using Offline Files in some places, you can configure how you'd like Offline Files to sync (or disable it completely) from User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Offline Files.

More information on how to configure specific settings here:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759721%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Are you also doing Folder Redirection?